# photoshop cs3 scripting - font names

Tags: photoshop-script, photoshop-cs3

i am trying to set the font of a textItem, using textItem.font which accepts a string, but i do not know the exact font names to refer in code,
i am trying to achieve something like this

```
var newLayer = docRef_1.artLayers.add();
newLayer.kind=LayerKind.TEXT;
var textItemRef = newLayer.textItem;
textItemRef.contents = someCharacter;
textItemRef.size = 120;
textItemRef.font="Verdana-Bold";
```

but the font names to refer in code are not the same as they appear in photoshop UI 
for e.g Arial is ArialMT, arial bold is Arial-BoldMT. Where can i get all the font names?
i could not find it in the javascript reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fonts available to Photoshop are listed in `app.fonts`. To list all fonts to the Extendscript Tools console, execute:

```
for (i=0; i< app.fonts.length; i++) {
    $.writeln(app.fonts[i].name);
}
```

You can use the `app.fonts.getByName('String')` method to call the first font in the `app.fonts` array that matches `String` in its name.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between the displayed font name and the internal font name. In your script you have to use the internal name. This function can help you:

```
var internalFontName = getInternalFontName("Trebuchet MS Bold");    

function getInternalFontName(pFontName) {
    for (var i = 0; i < app.fonts.length; i++) {
       if (pFontName == app.fonts[i].postScriptName) {
           return pFontName; // already is an internal font name.
       }
       if (pFontName == app.fonts[i].name) {
           return app.fonts[i].postScriptName; // found an internal name.
       }
   }   
   return null;
}
```