# Find available fonts in Adobe After Effects with extendscript

Tags: fonts, adobe, extendscript, after-effects

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20575016/photoshop-cs3-scripting-font-names/20589255#20589255) it shows you can find the fonts available to Photoshop by looking at the app.fonts property. But of course that doesn't work in After Effects because Adobe.

[image: ☠☢↯†☭‼ Adobe]

Is there a way of listing the available fonts so that I can write a script that lets the user choose a font?

Answer (score 2):

Looking through the AE script reference, it doesn't seem as if AE has a way of accessing the fonts collection like PS and AI do... That being said, I came up with a workaround for PC using the After Effects **system.callSystem()** method to pass the font gathering process off to PowerShell and using ScriptUI in AE to prompt the user for their selection.  For more info on ScriptUI, see the document written by Peter Kahrel [here](https://www.rebel-ist.com/img/example/scriptui-2-16-j.pdf).

This is a working example, but has only been tested in AE CC2019 on PC running Windows 10.  In AE, you need to make sure the option **Allow Scripts to Write Files and Access Network** under ***Preferences > Scripting & Expressions*** is enabled.

1. Create a powershell file named getFonts.ps1 and save it to your desktop (or anywhere you please, just be sure to update the jsx file with the new location).  Then copy and paste the following code:

   ```
   [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Drawing')
   $fontList = (New-Object System.Drawing.Text.InstalledFontCollection)

   # save a file to the desktop with a list of all the fonts
   $fontFile = "~/Desktop/fonts.txt"

   # since we use Add-Content, we are appending to the file.  
   # Delete the file on run if it exists so we don't continue appending to the list
   if (Test-Path $fontFile) {
       Remove-Item $fontFile
   }

   # loop through the collection and write each font name to fonts.txt on the desktop
   for ($i = 0; $i -lt $fontList.Families.Length; $i++) {
       # $fontObjs.add($fontList.Families[$i].Name)
       $fontNames = $fontList.Families[$i].Name 
       Add-Content $fontFile "$fontNames"
   }
   ```
2. Create a new jsx file named textFonts.jsx.  Copy and paste the following:

   ```js
   // powershell file location
   var pathToPs1File = "~/Desktop/getFonts.ps1"
   // execute powershell file
   var fonts = system.callSystem("Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass " + pathToPs1File)

   // Give the powershell script some time (3 seconds in this case) to write all the font names
   // it may need more time if you have 1000s of fonts, adjust as needed
   $.sleep(3000)

   // function to parse through the fonts pulled from the text file
   // will return array of font names for ScriptUI
   function getAllFonts(fontsFromFile) {

       fontsFromFile = fontsFromFile.split("\n");
       var fontListForScriptUI = []
       for (i = 0; i < fontsFromFile.length; i++) {
           if (!fontsFromFile[i]) {
               continue;
           }
           else {
               fontListForScriptUI.push(fontsFromFile[i])
           }
       }
       return fontListForScriptUI;
   }

   // Script UI will return the *name* of the font chosen.
   function main() {

       //surpress error dialogs
       app.beginSuppressDialogs()
       var scriptVersion = 1.0;

       var fontFile = File("~/Desktop/fonts.txt");

       fontFile.open("e")
       var fontList = fontFile.read();
       fontFile.close();

       var allFonts = getAllFonts(fontList);

       //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
       //
       // Options Dialog
       //
       //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

       var options = new Window('dialog', 'Test Script ' + scriptVersion);
           options.alignChildren = ['fill', 'top'];
           options.graphics.font = ScriptUI.newFont ("Segoe UI", "Regular", 14);

       if (app.version == "13.0.1") { // if its CS6, font color is dark, otherwise font color is light
           options.graphics.foregroundColor = options.graphics.newPen (options.graphics.PenType.SOLID_COLOR, [0.2, 0.2, 0.2], 1);
       }
       else {
           options.graphics.foregroundColor = options.graphics.newPen (options.graphics.PenType.SOLID_COLOR, [1,1,1,], 1);
       }

       //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
       // List Font Names
       //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

       var groupOptions = options.add('panel', undefined, 'Font Picker');
           groupOptions.orientation = 'column';
           groupOptions.alignChildren = 'left';
           groupOptions.margins = 30;
           groupOptions.indent = 30;
           groupOptions.graphics.font = ScriptUI.newFont ("Segoe UI", "Regular", 14);

           groupOptions.add('statictext', undefined, 'System Fonts:');

       var fontList = groupOptions.add('dropdownlist', undefined, allFonts);
           fontList.preferredSize.width = 300;

       //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
       // OK & Cancel Buttons
       //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

       var btns = options.add('group {alignment: "right" }');
           btns.orientation = 'row';
       var okButton = btns.add('button', undefined, 'OK', { name: 'ok' });
       var canButton = btns.add('button', undefined, 'Cancel', { name: 'cancel' });

       var myResult = options.show();

       if (myResult == 2) {
           // on cancel, alert the user and exit the script
           alert("Operation Canceled!");
           exit(0);
       }

       options.close();
       return fontList.selection.text
   }

   // store the returned value for later as pickedFont
   var pickedFont = main();

   alert(pickedFont);
   ```

Finally, run the jsx file in AE.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping not to have to use the shell—particularly as the users for this script are cross-platform—but it looks like the only way.

Comment: Here's the Powershell command I used - since Powershell has a built in convertTo-json function it's much simpler just to convert the installedFontCollection object to json and save that, then it's in a language that you can easily read into your script: `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Drawing'); (convertTo-json(New-Object System.Drawing.Text.InstalledFontCollection))>$env:temp\fontlist.txt`